# Split the comma separated values using Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to split the values from the String and add it to an array where I use it to display values in a drop down manner in Vuejs

```
String val1 = "abc,123,676,uuu".
```

Once iterated

```
          <li v-for = "val in valList" :key="val.index"> {{val}}</li>

     abc
     123
     676
     uuu
```

Comment: straightforward `.split(",")` right?

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = 'Harry,John,Clark,Peter,Rohn,Alice';
var nameArr = names.split(',');
console.log(nameArr);
```

[reference](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-into-an-array-in-javascript.php)

Comment: this.list.forEach((val)=>{  if (val.name !==null} {   this.mainList.push(val.name.split(',')}}).  I have name which may contain comma separated or single value.I need to push it to mainList. But I see the values like [abc,123,676,uuu] and [777] displaying under drop down